# How to Install NightCode IDE for Clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I already have JDK, Leningen and installed ClojureTools in powershell. Now I need editor to work and I have downloaded ZIP file of github project of NightCode but I don't know how to install this NightCode and use this as editor. I'm a beginner and just now getting to know about Clojure. Please anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/oakes/Nightcode) you have to build the jar file for your os:

```
To build the uberjar for each OS:

    clj -A:prod uberjar windows
    clj -A:prod uberjar macos
    clj -A:prod uberjar linux
```

Then you get a standalone uberjar (a Java ARchive file) that you can run with Java:

`java -jar target/nightcode-2.8.4-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`. Then the Nightcode editor starts.